# Near address checksum

Tags: nearprotocol

is there a way to check if address is a valid near address? Currently I've implemented the rules from their docs (https://docs.near.org/concepts/basics/accounts/account-id)

Is there a checksum check I can additionally apply? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Those rules validate the correctness of the identifier. If you want to validate the existence of the account on the network, you can [query the blockchain through RPC](https://docs.near.org/api/rpc/contracts#view-account).